# using multi db in Django - authentication directed to wrong database

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-orm

I am working with a multi database setting in Django. One is for business stuff (--database=default), and the other one stores user information (--database=users). Below is the view for the app that would be using the 'users' database:

```
def auth_and_login(request):
    global user
    post = request.POST
    if post['email'] is u'' or post['password'] is u'':
        s = 'Please check login input forms'
        return render_to_response('insecure.html', {'s': s})
    else:
        user = authenticate(username=post['email'], password=post['password'])
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            s = 'Logged in  ' + user.first_name + '  ' + user.last_name
            return render_to_response('loggedin.html', {'s': s})
        else:
            s = 'Login fails'
            return render_to_response('insecure.html', {'s': s})

def create_user(username, email, password):
    global user
    user = User(username=username, email=email).using('users')
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def user_exists(username):
    user_count = User.objects.using('users').filter(username=username).count()
    if user_count == 0:
        return False
    return True

def sign_up_in(request):
    global user
    post = request.POST
    if post['email'] is u'' or post['password'] is u'':
        s = 'Please check sign-up input forms'
        return render_to_response('upsecure.html', {'s': s})
    else:
        if not user_exists(post['email']):
            user = create_user(username=post['email'], email=post['email'], password=post['password'])
        user.first_name=post['first']
        user.last_name=post['last']
        user.save()
        s = 'Sign Up Successful   ' + user.first_name + '  ' + user.last_name
    else:
        s = 'Existing User'
    return render_to_response('upsecure.html', {'s': s})
```

When a user signs up, the information is stored in the correct database. However, it is not possible to log in with the information because the authentication is directed to the other database. What should I do to make authentication be routed to the right database?

Comment: write your own AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND and appropriate settings change in your settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up an auth router for the auth calls you can specify that database for the other signup model within the auth router

```
if model._meta.app_label == 'signup/whatever':
    return 'name_of_auth_db'
```